# Mocha Unit Test Case Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am facing the problem in mocking function which is being called from other function while writing the unit test cases in Node JS. I am using sinon chai and mocha to write the unit test case in my application. Below is my code

````
    if (req.body.escalationDay === undefined) {
      throw new Error('\'escalationDay\' attribute is required');
    }

    const escalationDay = req.body.escalationDay;
    const invoiceId = req.params.id;
    const lineItemNumber = req.params.lineItemNumber;
    const invoice = await doGetInvoiceById(invoiceId, req);

    if (!invoice) {
      console.log("hi i am in")
      throw new Error(`No invoice found with id ${invoiceId}`);
    }

    if (!invoice.InvoiceLineItems) {
      throw new Error(`No line items found for invoice with id ${invoiceId}`);
    }

    const lineItem = invoice.InvoiceLineItems.find(li => +li.Id === +lineItemNumber);

    if (!lineItem) {
      throw new Error(`No line items with line item id ${lineItem.Id} found for invoice with id ${invoiceId}`);
    }
 }```

and below is the unit test case I am writing for this function

```  it('Should test escalation', () => {
        let mockReq = {
            params: {
                id: '5f6bfc693b2253001a140cba',
                lineItemNumber: 1
            },
            body: { escalationDay: 0 },
            query: {
                system: "test"
            }
        };
        let sinonStub = sinon.stub(service(reqHandler, microservicesettings), 'doGetInvoiceById');
        sinonStub.withArgs('5f6bfc693b2253001a140cba', mockReq).returns(
            { InvoiceLineItems : [] }
        );
        
        assert.equal(InvoiceService(reqHandler, microservicesettings).doInvoiceLineItemEscalation(mockReq)).to.be.equal( { InvoiceLineItems : [] });
        
    })```

It will be good if I can get any idea what i am missing
````

Comment: In order to get help you should describe the concrete issue you're are facing and provide the whole code under test and the whole of the test it self in order to get help.